# An input appears when selecting an option

Tags: jquery, input

I'm trying to create a form that brings the order number to the client select "Yes" or "no" this is my code

**Contato.phtml**

```
...
        <li>
            <label for="f_f_compra" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Já realizou sua compra?') ?></label>
                <div class="select">
                    <select id="f_f_compra" name="f_f_compra" class=" required-entry required-entry select">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Selecione --</option>
                    <option value='Sim' >Sim</option>
                    <option value='Não' >Não</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
        </li>
            <li id="pedido" style="display:none;" >
                    <li class="wide">
                        <label for="pedido" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Pedido') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input name="increment_id" id="increment_id" value="" class="input-text required-entry" type="text">
                            <input name="pedido" id="pedido" value="0" type="hidden">
                        </div>
                    </li>
...
```

**JQuery code**

```
$jQuery('#f_f_compra').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "Sim") {
        document.getElementById("pedido").style.display="block";
        //jQuery alternative
        //$("#attach").show();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("pedido").style.display="none";
        //jQuery alternative
        //$("#attach").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try below:

```
document.getElementById("f_f_compra").onchange = function(){
    if (document.getElementById("f_f_compra").value == "Sim") {
        document.getElementById("pedido").style.display="block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("pedido").style.display="none";
    }
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ankgnvxg/2/

Also in my fiddle i changed the nested li elements

Comment: Thanks for the help, you are giving this error: Uncaught TypeError: Can not set property 'change' of null

Comment: Have you copied it exactly like in the fiddle above i have not got change in my code but onchange

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Did you get it going?

Comment: I'm doing a lot of research here, I think it might be a conflict between the prototype of magento and JQuery that I downloaded, but I already did the noconflict file so I think it might be blocking my jquery

Comment: Yeah that's a pain, the bit of code i gave you was pure javascript so shouldn't have any issues like that as i thought as much. But yeah that happens a lot in Magento 1

Comment: I was able to solve the conflict problem, I had to change this line `$ j ("f_f_compra"). Onchange = function () {`

No error, but also not performing the action

Comment: $j("#f_f_compra") with jquery?

Comment: Yes, because i use noConflict `jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: Yeah that is fine just i was stating the # for selecting element.

Comment: Still is not working, I will give one more researched here to try to solve, when I do I will return with the answer

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6pzxwptu/1 Here is my fiddle when in no conflict mode.

Comment: I put the code straight into phtml and it worked, could the error be in the jQuery call? My friend told me to put an onchange in the name f_f_compra, can it work? How can I do this

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean you can just add an onchange attribute to the element if that's what you mean. Where are you putting this js? It should be find to just have that little script in the phtml file tho.

Comment: I call in local.xml, but not phtml I do not call it anyway, do I have to put something in phtml for it to understand? I thought that just specifying the name in jQuery by f_f_compra he would already know

Comment: Is it maybe rendering your js before the jquery? But you would get an error then that $j is not define. It should work either way really but i can't quite tell without looking.

Comment: I'm going to use jQuery code directly in the html, in real I think that's how it has to do, right, I was creating a file in the jquery folder and calling it in xml afterwards, but since it's pure code it has to be In phtml, how am I dumb, omg, thanks for your help dear, seriously you gave me enough attention, thank you

Comment: No worries that's what i would do for a tiny script like that anyway. Glad its all sorted.

Comment: Harri, do you have any means of contact?

Comment: Yeah i do skype etc, what is up?

Comment: I am trying to do a function and it has to be for jQuery, and you are a specialist right? I would like an opinion

Comment: I wouldn't say specialist :P i can try help tho

Comment: Could you give me a call then?

Comment: Yeah can do what is your skype?